# How to convert cassandra to HDFS file system for shark/hive query

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, hdfs, apache-spark

Is there any way to expose cassandra data as HDFS and then perfom shark/Hive query on HDFS ??

If yes, kindly provide some links to transform cassandra db into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can write identity MapReduce Code which take input from CFS (cassandra filesystem) and dump data to HDFS.

Once you have data in HDFS , you can map a hive table and run queries.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to access Cassandra data in Hive is to use the CqlStorageHandler.
Details see [Hive Support for Cassandra CQL3](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/post/hive-support-for-cassandra-cql3).

But if you have some reasons to access the data directly, take a look at [Cassowary](https://github.com/richardalow/cassowary). It is a "Hive storage handler for Cassandra and Shark that reads the SSTables directly. This allows total control over the resources used to run ad-hoc queries so that the impact on real-time Cassandra performance is controlled."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run Hive/Shark against data already in Cassandra. If that is the case then you don't need to access it as HDFS but you need a hive-handler for using it against Cassandra.

For this you can use [Tuplejump's](http://www.tuplejump.com) project, [CASH](https://github.com/tuplejump/cash/blob/master/cassandra-handler/README.md) The Readme provides the instruction on how to build and use it. If you want to put your "big files" in Cassandra and query on them, like you do from HDFS, you will need a FileSystem that runs on Cassandra like [DataStax's](http://www.datastax.com) CFS present in DSE, or Tuplejump's SnackFS (present in the [Calliope Project](http://tuplejump.github.io/calliope/) Early Access Repo)

Disclaimer: I work for Tuplejump, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuplejump Calliope Project. 
https://github.com/tuplejump/calliope

Configure external Cassandra Table in Shark(like Hive) using Storage Handler provided in TumpleJump code.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Three cassandra hive storage

https://github.com/2013Commons/hive-cassandra for 2.0 and hadoop 2

https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-Cassandra/tree/HIVE-0.11.0-HADOOP-2.0.0-CASSANDRA-1.2.9

https://github.com/richardalow/cassowary directly from sstable